# Increasing xp dropped by mobs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can you increase the amount of xp dropped by mobs in 1.13?

I know I can make a system using commands that will give you xp when you kill a mob through scoreboards, but I was wondering if there's a way to do it straight at the source, maybe through data packs?
I thought maybe by making a loot table, but I don't understand how they work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loot tables can't contain XP.

The best you can do is to make an advancement with the [`minecraft:player_killed_entity` trigger](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Advancement#minecraft:player_killed_entity) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Advancements&oldid=1260690#minecraft:player_killed_entity)), the conditions you need and [experience points as a reward](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Advancement#JSON_Format) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Advancements&oldid=1260690#JSON_Format)). The advantage or disadvantage, depending on what you want, is that the XP won't be dropped as an item, but given directly.

If you want to drop the XP, you have to do what you already knew: Detect the kill and summon XP orbs yourself.